# strtok function const char pointer error

Tags: c

I keep getting the following Error

```
passing argument 1 of 'strtok' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

Through this line

```
for (char *p = strtok(season_info,"\n"); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
```

ps: season_info is defined like this:
 const char* season_info

Comment: That's basic constant correctness. It should be pretty clear why this function requires write access, too.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` needs to make changes to your string, so it can't operate on a `const char*` argument. You'll need to make a copy of that string before sending it to `strtok`.

Comment: So I need to do casting from const char* to char* ?

Comment: Casting is risky, dangerous, and a good way to get undefined behaviour. I'd avoid doing that. You need to make a copy.

Comment: Is there a specific function for that?

Comment: You should at least be familiar with the `str` family of functions available in the C Standard Library before using `strtok`. Take some time to familiarize yourself with them and you'll better understand the tools you have to solve problems like this.

Comment: @Yasmin12, you should not cast "const-away" because sometimes original char data may reside in a read-only memory and strtok() would crash with "access violation" error on very first modification attempt.